# What properties does the conductor making the plates for Casimir effect have?

Tags: regularization, casimir-effect

Reading [this](http://www.quora.com/Does-the-fact-that-zeta-function-regularization-works-in-physics-Casimir-effect-and-other-examples-too-point-to-an-intelligent-designers-handiwork-in-crafting-the-laws-of-physics) explanation, I've understood that the divergence in computation of [Casimir force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect) on two parallel conducting plates is because of an unphysical model of ideal conductor, which makes EM field vanish on its boundaries. This looks much like unphysical model of rigid body in relativistic mechanics.

Still, zeta regularization appears to somehow correctly remove the divergence and give sensible results. This must mean that effectively, it replaces our "too ideal" conductor with a "moderately ideal" one. So, the boundary conditions for EM field are no longer as simple as zero.

So, my question is now: what boundary conditions does zeta-regularization implicitly impose on the EM field instead of the original ones? Does such change of boundary conditions in fact mean that the force will depend on which conductor the plates are made of?

Comment: A conductor = an equipotential surface for this computation and fixes the boundary conditions on the EM field. The regularization has NOTHING to do with boundary conditions which exist even in the classical version discussed in a first course in E&M. Finally, the Casimir effect is a finite size effect which may be attributed to the boundary conditions -- however there is nothing unphysical about the boundary conditions. Capacitors are classic examples.

Comment: @suresh Of course, technically regularization doesn't mention boundary conditions at all. But what it seems to do (follow the link at the very beginning of the question for the explanation) is remove those EM modes which should have penetrated the conductor thus making it not ideal, but were taken as ideally confined at the beginning of computation. See what I mean: even a sheet of e.g. aluminium will get penetrated by e.g. X or gamma rays, although it is conductor. Thus, it's not an ideal conductor.

Comment: One can incorporate that kind of behaviour by imposing mixed boundary conditions instead of pure Dirichlet boundary conditions. Nevertheless, the Casimir effect will remain and it has been measured in the lab.